# Is it conceivable to have the Heisenberg uncertainty to take on a different value?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, physical-constants, multiverse

Would it be possible to conceive of a universe in which the maximal precision of measurement is greater or less than the current value? If so, what macroscopic effect would it have? Would it fundamentally change certain mechanisms such as stellar nucleosynthesis?

Comment: We're talking about different values of Planck's constant, $h$?

Comment: To reopen this post (v2), consider to include published reference and definition of a 'parallel universe' or 'multiverse'.

Comment: It is inconceivable, because the law $\Delta p \Delta x\ge \hbar/2$ follows from the [canonical commutation relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$. You can't change the Heisenberg uncertainty principle without changing $\hbar$. But h bar is a dimensionful quantity, so changing it is just equivalent to scaling our units and so [isn't physically meaningful](http://motls.blogspot.com/2009/06/changes-of-dimensionful-quantities-are.html). The limit can't be changed so long as quantum mechanics and the canonical commutation relation holds.

Comment: I removed the word "parallel" and voted to reopen as I don't think "parallel universe" is meant to be taken literally. I think it's a valid question that's basically asking "how rigid is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle".

Comment: We all know more or less what OP means by multiverse, and unfortunately, multiverse is mainstream physics now :/ so I'm voting reopen

Comment: Since $h$ is dimensionful and one may pick units st $h=1$ , I don't think different values are themselves physically different.

Comment: in particle physics  calculations are invariant in assuming natural https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_unitsunits